# Touchpad does not work on Acer Aspire

Tags: linux, touchpad

I have an Acer Aspire on which I installed Linux Mint 17.2. The touchpad does not work at all; xinput doesn't even list any touchpad unit at all. Probably a driver issue, is there some way to make it work?

Comment: even if you're providing the answer yourself, you should still phrase this as a question.

Comment: For me it was enough to re-enable touchpad by typing <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. I have Debian stretch LXDE...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution: add `i8042.nopnp` to the kernel command line. To do this:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

and add:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nopnp"
```

If there's already a line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=…`, add `i8042.nopnp` inside the quotes, separated from any other word within the quotes by a space, e.g.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="some-other=option i8042.nopnp"
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot. Hope it works, it worked for me!

Comment: Had the same problem on Acer TravelMate B. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Also worked for Aspire One Cloudbook 14 and Ubuntu 20.04 with Kde

Comment: Struggling with this with an Aspire 1 A115-32. Make sure the Touchpad is set to 12c in the BIOS, and then this worked like a charm.

Comment: Worked perfectly on a clean Lubuntu installation after updates, curious to know what `i8042.nopnp` do/has though...

Answer (score 5):

For acer laptops,
After installing drivers if it's still not working.

then you have To re-enable your touchpad: On your laptop keyboard, press the `Fn` key and the `F6 or F7` key (the function key with a touchpad icon on it) at the same time. Then check to see if you're able to use your touchpad.

So try clicking or swiping after pressing the keys mentioned, to see it's enabled.

**Source:** https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/acer-laptop-touchpad-not-working-solved/

Comment: and then, will it work or not?

Comment: yes it will. try clicking or swiping after pressing the keys mentioned. to see its enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Menu -> Administration -> Update Manager -> (Install Updates -- Ensure you Update the kernel) -> reboot -> Fn - F7

Inspired by : http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-mint-touchpad-fix.html

Linux Mint Serena - Aspire V3-575-5OTD (Updated to kernel v4.4.0-62)

Answer (score 1):

Try F7. I had this same problem installing Mint on Acer Aspire 5. I tried as suggested Fn + F7 but it did not work. My F7 key has a picture of a touchpad on it, so it is used to enable/disable touchpad. It worked when I did not use Fn key, just F7.

Comment: You saved my night ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it *all*...

- In my research there was talk of blacklisting I2C modules to force alternate modules to manage the synaptic touchpad. So my suspicions were confirmed when I found the `i2c_i801` module blacklisted by default in LinuxMint - Serena. I un-blacklisted it, reboot and viola -- the return of the functional touchpad.
- I also changed the touchpad mode to BASIC in the BIOS. Not the most elegant solution but it does work reliably. the touch pad can be disabled and re-enabled as needed via <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>

I say not the most elegant as the USB receiver or attached mouse has to be disconnected at boot time and plugged in after the system is up if required.

Brief how to below. Note: Words in between `/* .. */` are comments.

- Open blacklist (in `vi` in this example)

  ```
  sudo vi  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
  ```
- In VI.. search for the i2c blacklisting by typing:

  ```
  \i2c
  ```
- Then comment the line jumped to by preceeding with a hashtag

  ```
  I[press enter]#
  ```
- You should have:

  ```
  #blacklist i2c_i801
  ```
- Now save and exit by:

  ```
  [press 'Esc' key]:wq!
  ```

Answer (score 0):

After going through lots of bug reports and solutions, managed to boot kubuntu 19.10, kernel 5.3 with a working touchpad (elan).
My device is

- ACER Aspire 3 A315-41-R955
- bios 1.13 version
- AMD Ryzen 5 2500U cpu

**Steps:**

1. disable secure boot in bios settings
2. Add these two lines in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 nosplash irqpoll"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.elantech_smbus=0"
```

3. `sudo update-grub`

Thats all.